# Process a pandas DataFrame in Chunks or optimize memory usage for aggregation features

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I'm working on a Jupyter notebook in Python with Pandas for data analysis.

When creating new aggregation features, I encounter a "MemoryError" due to the memory capacity of my system.

Before this error occurs, I'm performing operations similar to the following code:

```py
# Sum Operations
operation_fields = [column for column in data.columns if 'Operations' in column]
data['Operations'] = data[operation_fields].apply(lambda row: sum(row), axis=1)
for operation_field in operation_fields:
    data[f'Operations_{operation_field}_vs_total'] = np.where(
        data['Operations'] == 0,
        np.floor(data['Operations']),
        np.floor(data[operation_field] / data['Operations'] * 100)
    )
```

This results in the data having the following dimensions:

- Size: 17741115
- Columns: 85
- Rows: 208719

After that, I attempt to execute the following code to calculate new features based on transactions:

```py
# Sum transactions
transaction_fields = [column for column in data.columns if 'Transactions' in column and 'SavingAccount' in column]
data['Transactions'] = data[transaction_fields].apply(lambda row: sum(row), axis=1)
for transaction_field in transaction_fields:
    data[f'Transactions_{transaction_fields}_vs_total'] = np.where(
        data['Transactions'] == 0,
        np.floor(data['Transactions']),
        np.floor(data[transaction_fields] / data['Transactions'] * 100)
    )
```

However, I encounter the error message: "MemoryError: Unable to allocate 325. GiB for an array with shape (208719, 208719) and data type float64."

I'm looking for guidance on how to process this large dataset efficiently.

Options:

- A way to process this dataset in smaller "chunks" to avoid memory errors.
- Strategies to optimize memory usage when working with large Pandas DataFrames for aggregation features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never heard about [vectorization](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/pandas-vectorization/)?

```
# vectorized sum, which is more memory efficient
data['Transactions'] = data[transaction_fields].sum(axis=1)
```

```
# numpy to avoid the explicit loop
transaction_ratios = data[transaction_fields].div(data['Transactions'], axis=0)
transaction_ratios = transaction_ratios.multiply(100).fillna(0).astype(int)

for transaction_field in transaction_fields:
    data[f'Transactions_{transaction_field}_vs_total'] = transaction_ratios[transaction_field]
```

This should help. Alternatively you can explore [Polars](https://www.pola.rs/) which is rapidly gaining traction in the data ecosystem.

Comment: Thank you, with this change, the code runs successfully and more quickly.